# What reports are available out of SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, reports

I've been researching Out of the Box and third party reporting tools to no avail.

I would like to track how users are using sites in the company.  SharePoint adoption is the measure of success of a deployment, hence the need for such reports.  For example:

- What sites are accessed.
- Who is accessing the site. How long they
  spend on the site.
- What content is being accessed. etc.
- etc...

How are most companies addressing such needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 provide a number of OOTB **Audit log reports** , to enable administrators to view the data in the audit logs to track how SharePoint site contents are being used and determine user activities on sites, lists, libraries, content types, list items, and library files in the site collection.

[View audit log reports](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-audit-log-reports-63b045b1-05ee-407d-a2ea-92b4ba0eef6e) 
[Configure audit settings for a site collection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2)